# MFC dialog and form

Tags: c++, mfc, opencv

I have a dialog (there are 3 edit controls in order to display 3 color channels RGB), I use openCV to open an image in a new form. What I want is when I move the mouse to any point on the image, each of the RGB color values will be shown in 3 edit boxed (on the dialog). How can I do that?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:
[OpenCV rgb value for cv::Point in cv::Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747920/opencv-rgb-value-for-cvpoint-in-cvmat)

To get the current cursor position you can use [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and eventually [ScreenToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms932582.aspx) functions.